# String manipulation, removing characters until the second occurrence in java script

Tags: javascript, string

How to remove all the characters until you encounter second comma(,) in the sentence in js?

I have something like this in my string:

```
var str = "hello,abc,def,jkl,mno,pqr,stu";
```

I want the string to contain something like this:

```
str = "def,jkl,mno,pqr,stu"
```

How to do something like this?

Is there way to do this other than putting in loop checking for comma then erasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert to array with `split`.
2. Cut array with `slice`
3. Join the array with `join`.

```js
var str = "hello,abc,def,jkl,mno,pqr,stu";
var arr = str.split(',');
var newStr = arr.slice(2, arr.length).join(',')
console.log(newStr)
```